# SQL inserting in to a table more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am trying to inserting two rows in to my table using subquery.

The HISTORYTEACHEAS relation has (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)

```
insert into HISTORYTEACHES
values('2',(select c.course_id from HISTORYCOURSE c where c.course_id like '2%'),'1','Spring','2016');
```

The ID,sec_id, semester and year are set, course_id are what need to be found, so I use the subquery from finding it. The subquery alone has two results.

I need to insert both into the table at once, but can't figure out how, as this kind of insertion can only have one-row result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert into` with `select` instead:

```
insert into HISTORYTEACHES
select '2', course_id, '1', 'Spring', '2016'
from HISTORYCOURSE 
where course_id like '2%'
```

Btw, inserting the value 2 into an `id` field seems odd.  Perhaps that should be auto increment instead.  Also if those are integer values, remove the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! :)